# BDD And Unit Testing

Tags: .net, tdd, bdd

I have been doing TDD and was using it more as unit testing than to drive my design.  Recently I have read a lot about BDD; now that I have a better idea about them both, I was trying to figure out how to use BDD and unit testing concurrently.

For example I would drive my design using BDD, Dan North style, and lets say I am working on an app and I have a simple spec and I implement it. I have just enough bdd/spec to cover it. Now after I've re-factored it and am happy and it's passed as done for that spec, should I start writing Unit tests to cover all possible inputs, because that's what I did in TDD?

I am the only developer in the company and everything is on my shoulders, although the other team do try to manual test the app, I would like to lower the defect rate.

Comment: So can we see an actual answer to _Should I start writing Unit tests to cover all possible inputs, because that's what I did in TDD_? I seriously have the same question and don't think that link to the book (even if it's sooo cool) is good enough to accept it.

Comment: jibie Your right I have added an answer my self. albeit late!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pick up "The RSpec Book". The book uses Cucumber & RSpec. Could easily be Cucumber & NUnit or something else though. Cucumber and BDD extend the red, green, refactor concept a level deeper.

http://www.pragprog.com/titles/achbd/the-rspec-book

Cucumber: http://cukes.info/
RSpec: http://rspec.info/
NUnit: http://www.nunit.org/
JUnit: http://www.junit.org/

Comment: I agree, this book is great. And Cucumber is possible to use with .NET as well.

Comment: Yep, and Java. Cuke for Nuke and Cuke for Duke.

Comment: Got the book now , and I must say its awesome.

Comment: Good, it's a great book. Glad you agree.

Comment: Also have a look at SpecFlow (www.specflow.org). It is a pure .NET tool and tries to bring pragmatic BDD to .NET.

Answer (score 0):

I agree. The *RSpec Book* book does a decent job of describing the "Outside - In" approach to development. Cucumber (outside) helps describe the expected behavior (in terms that the user understands); and RSpec/*Unit (inside) helps to describe your class' behavior.

Comment: Outside-in starts with the scenarios in Cucumber, but then the idea is that you work from the user interfaces inwards through controllers, repositories, services etc. until your scenario passes. You never write code which isn't needed by a class closer to the user interface (users can be other systems). Even at a class level we do the "outside" classes first.