# Understanding testing (BDD) — Can I skip Unit Test duplicating something that is already covered in certain Integration Test?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, integration-testing, bdd

*Note: There was the similar question before ( [BDD And Unit Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329039/bdd-and-unit-testing) ) but it doesn't have an actual straight answer. Just link to the book.*

Assume we test a profile page. User submit his data.

- Validation failed — we notify him about it, object not updated.
- Validation passed — he's redirected to profile page with submitted data. Object updated. Cool!

So if I've tested that validations are working properly during BDD do I need to double-check it with Unit Test? Or I can skip it? What will the right thing to do in this case and why?

Comment: Integration tests are typically slow. Unit tests are fast, because they only touch one object, don't use the database or filesystem, etc. Once you have 10,000 tests, you'll care about being able to run just the unit tests instead of having to wait for the integration tests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Integration test checks your parts are working together in right manner.

Unit test covers right functionality of each part itself.

So, there are two parts of the answer:

1. No, you should not skip it. Integration tests tested your validation in context of the whole page including all its modules. A module that does validation should definitely have Unit Test that test this, as well (in isolation, as Unit Tests do).
2. You never test same things with Integration tests and with Unit Tests. In integration test you tested the page behaves such and such with certain inputs. In Unit Test you can even ignore you are in a page, if you are testing a self-containing module. Even if that module validates some data and does some decisions. You only Unit Test that validation process and outcome of that decision.

Comment: Thanks, a bit clearer for me. Might give **The RSpec Book** a try actually.

Answer (score 3):

If the validation logic is simple, go ahead and ignore the TDD dogma. You won't gain much from "proper" unit tests.

But if the validation is complex, you probably won't be able to test every corner case in an integration tests (or if you do, the tests will take a very long time to run and be fragile, i.e. break often for various reasons, and when they break it will sometimes be hard to determine why.

Unit tests suffer much less from these problems, so they can be useful to complement the integration tests.

Comment: May I ask you what's TDD dogma? Is it regarding to unit testing somehow?

Comment: @jibiel: TDD dogma is that you must have unit tests for every class, the class must be tested in complete isolation using mocks, and every test must test exactly one thing. No exceptions allowed, and if it's too hard then you must refactor until it's not. I happen to think that this is a nice ideal to aspire to, but often impractical and inefficient, and that you *can* get much of the benefit without following all the rules all the time.

Comment: In TDD view, test are not for testing (what you sure know, just to add the second view for others). Tests are 1. development tool to keep you on the path of creating simple code with good design (that is what your complaints on "you must refactor until it's not" - if it is not easily testable, you have a design problem); 2. they serve as an (executable) documentation of the code features; and only 3. (as a pleasant side-effect, I'd say) is their ability to automatically test the code behaves correctly. You can loose the rules, but not before you know why they are. For that you must use them.

Comment: @Michael - `...in complete isolation using mocks` is not part of TDD. That is like trying to say that refactoring is TDD. Doesn't make sense. Mocks and refactoring are tools!